# Setting a relative path in crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have written the following code,

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument report = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
report.Load(@"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Backup1\Project\ReportsFolder\ReportSalesInvoice.rpt");
```

Report works fine for the above code But I want to give a relative path so I can install it in several machines without changing the path.
I have also tried the following paths

```
string loc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string loc2 = Application.StartupPath;
string loc3 = Application.UserAppDataPath;
string loc4 = Application.CommonAppDataPath;
```

Used them as,

```
report.Load(loc2 + "\\ReportSalesInvoice.rpt");
```

But the file cannot be accessed.Please Help.

Comment: What about `Environment.CurrentDirectory`? It is normally the base for relative files.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the file cannot be accessed'? Are you getting an exception when trying to Load()?

Comment: Why not adding the report to your project so that it will always be an integral part of your solution and more "exception safe"? This will make the need to load it from an outer path obsolete...

Comment: Yes, It gives the Exception,that it cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @Urik can you please explain what do you mean by adding report to your project ? even if had add the report to project will still need to add the path of the report

Comment: @samer I mean that you can add the RPT to your VS solution and then the environment creates specific objects for that report. Then, you don't need to load it at runtime.

Comment: @Urik umm i will try it ... thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

haven't tested in windows app, but this is what I use in MVC3. I believe the relative path has to be within the root of your application though

```
    using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
    using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

    using (var report = new ReportClass { FileName = Server.MapPath("/AppName/Reports/MyReport.rpt") })
    {
        report.Load();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Crystal_rpt()
{
  ReportDocument dir = new ReportDocument();
  dir = functions.Show_Crystal_rpt();
  dir.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\rptObt_mark.rpt");
  crpMark_sheet.ReportSource = dir;
}
```